# IO Image reading and writing: Is writing array of bytes different from writing byte at a time using write(int b) method?

Tags: java, io

I am new to java IO and I tried to simply copy and paste a photo. I used two ways to achieve this the first works nicely but the second doesn't.

This Code works fine.

```java
try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("photoOriginal.jpg"));
             BufferedOutputStream output =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("photoCopy.jpg"))) {
            try {
                int n =0;
                byte[] buf = new byte[4092];
                while((n = input.read(buf))!=-1){
                    output. Write(buf,0,n);
                    output.flush();
                }
} 
  } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

But the second doesn't work , after the program finished I find the copy File with the same exact size as the original but when trying to open it ,it shows format not supported error.

```java
try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("photoOriginal.jpg"));
             BufferedOutputStream output =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("photoCopy.jpg"))) {
            try {
                int byteRead = input.read();
                while (byteRead != -1) {
                    byteRead = input.read();
                    output.write(byteRead);
                    output.flush();
                }

                }
} 
  } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I don't understand where the problem is, it seems that the 2 sample are doing the same thing.
Is reading to and writing from byte array different from reading and writing single byte at a time ?
Isn't writing int to a Stream with **write(int b)** method only writes the lowest 8 bits and vice versa as said in Documentation ?

> write
> public abstract void write(int b)
> throws IOException
> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the **eight low-order bits** of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

hope someone will help.

Comment: By the way, Java has a [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) method.

Comment: write(int) just read one byte; write(buffer) write with... buffer. write(int) can be converted to char if it's text: `(char)b`; but it's binary in your case so no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not writing out the first byte - you call `input.read()`, check that it's not -1, but then call `input.read()` again:

```java
// Broken code
int byteRead = input.read();
while (byteRead != -1) {
    byteRead = input.read();
    output.write(byteRead);
    output.flush();
}
```

If you just move the next `input.read()` call to the end of the loop, it will work:

```java
// Working code with duplication
int byteRead = input.read();
while (byteRead != -1) {
    output.write(byteRead);
    output.flush();
    byteRead = input.read();
}
```

Or you could combine the "read and test" to avoid duplication:

```java
// Working code without duplication
int byteRead;
while ((byteRead = input.read()) != -1) {
    output.write(byteRead);
    output.flush();
}
```

However, this is still a *very* inefficient way of copying a stream. Copying a chunk at a time, as per your first code, is much more efficient (or using the built-in `transferTo` method if you're using Java 9 or higher, as rostamn79 notes).

Comment: thanks, yes the fixed code takes too much time, Is there a difference between If I flush the output stream every time I write or flush after the while loop?

Comment: @Mahmoud-310: I'd expect so - but it's easy for you to test. Is there any reason you want to persist with the inefficient code in the first place though?

Comment: no just for understanding, i tried both and both worked but I am asking is there a scenario where i must flush every time after i write despite of that i just want the final written data.

Answer (score 0):

Baeldung.com provides information on stream.transferTo() method which does not incur an additional copy to Java heap

https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-to-outputstream

Example code

```java
@Test
public void givenUsingJavaNine_whenCopyingInputStreamToOutputStream_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    String initialString = "Hello World!";

    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());
         ByteArrayOutputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        inputStream.transferTo(targetStream);

        assertEquals(initialString, new String(targetStream.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

See how this `transferTo` is called with both streams as arguments